# como inhabilitar el boton de refrescar de Internet Explorer con javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando inhabilitar el botón refrescar del navegador mediante javascript, hasta ahora solo he logrado hacer la inhabilitación de pulsar una combinación de teclas, pero no he logrado el evento del botón, tengo este código para eso:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.key == "F5") {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }
```

El botón al que hago referencia es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/849655/I-want-to-disable-refresh-button-of-browser y https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968580/how-to-disable-refresh-button-from-browsers-menu-bar?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score -1):

**No se puede deshabilitar** la funcionalidad del botón de retroceso del navegador. Lo único **si se puede hacer es evitarla**.
A continuación dejo el código de JavaScript que debe colocarse en la sección principal de la página donde desea que el usuario **NO** retroceda con el botón *atrás*:

```js
<script>
  function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
  setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
  window.onunload=function(){null};
</script>
```

Comment: Están hablando del botón refrescar, no de retroceso.

Comment: cierto es el boton refrescar no retroceso